# Multidimensional array with key

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, key

I have a typical multidimensional array but I need to add something like a key for each sub array. Like JSON.

An example structure:

```
{
    "0":
    {
        "1":
        {
            {1, 5, 9, 55}
        },
        "5":
        {
            {97, 82, 5}
        }
    },
    "2":
    {
        "0":
        {
            {9}
        },
        "2":
        {
            {3, 2, 2, 1, 4}
        }
    },
    "10":
    {
        "6":
        {
            {9, 10}
        },
        "7":
        {
            {0, 8, 2}
        }
    }
}
```

I will try to explain it on an example:

```
variable[0] would be equal "0"
variable[1] would be equal "2"
variable[3] would be equal "10"

variable[0][0] would be equal "1"
variable[0][1] would be equal "5"

variable[1][0] would be equal "0"
variable[1][1] would be equal "2"

variable[0][0][0] would be equal "1"
variable[0][0][1] would be equal "5"
variable[0][0][2] would be equal "9"
variable[0][0][3] would be equal "55"

variable[0][1][0] would be equal "97"
variable[0][1][1] would be equal "82"
variable[0][1][2] would be equal "5"
```

I would be able to do it by using more variables but I have quite a lot data that I might need to change in the future so I need them structured like above. What is the most efficient solution to do this in C#?

I tried multidimensional dictionary but its syntax is wrong:

```
Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, string>>>> scope = new Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, string>>>>()
{
    {
        0,
        {
            1,
            {
                1,
                {
                    1, "test"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
textBox1.Text = scope[0][0][0][0];
```

What is wrong there?

And one more question. Do these brackets: "()" belong at the end of this:

`Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, string>>>> scope = new Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, string>>>>()`?

Comment: _these brackets: "()"_  are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried multidimensional dictionary but its syntax is wrong

In the initializer syntax you can only add simple constants (like `int` and `string`) directly. You need new objects (Dictionaries) so it becomes:

```
var scope = new Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, string>>>>
{
    { 0, new Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, string>>>
          {
             { 0,  new Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, string>>
                  ...
             }
          }
    },
    { 1, new Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, Dictionary<byte, string>>>
          {
             ...
          }
    },

};
```

- there is no point in using `byte` here. Always use `int` when you need a small number.

Comment: Thanks. And why shouldn't I use byte? It doesn't exceed 255.

Comment: `int` is the default (optimized) type. You need special reasons to use `byte` or `short`, not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntax problems pointed out by [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18303506/1715579), you initialize your sub-dictionaries with a key of 1 so this:

```
textBox1.Text = scope[0][0][0][0];
```

With throw a `KeyNotFoundException`. This should work:

```
textBox1.Text = scope[0][1][1][1];
```

And no, you do not need the parentheses when calling a parameterless constructor using using an initializer like that.

However, I'd recommend using a `Dictionary<Tuple<byte, byte, byte, byte>, string>` instead, so you can do this:

```
var scope = new Dictionary<Tuple<byte, byte, byte, byte>, string>
{
    {
        Tuple.Create<byte, byte, byte, byte>(0, 1, 1, 1), "test"
    }
};

textBox1.Text = scope[Tuple.Create<byte, byte, byte, byte>(0, 1, 1, 1)];
```

And if you use a `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int, int>, string>` the syntax is a little more graceful:

```
var scope = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int, int>, string>
{
    {
        Tuple.Create(1, 1, 1), "test"
    }
};

textBox1.Text = scope[Tuple.Create(0, 1, 1, 1)];
```

Or you could create your own class that wraps this up and provides a more convenient indexer:

```
public class MyMultiKeyDictionary : 
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<Tuple<int, int, int, int>, string>>
{
    private Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int, int>, string> dict;

    public string this[int w, int x, int y, int z]
    {
        get { return this.dict[Tuple.Create(w, x, y, z)]; }
        set { this.dict[Tuple.Create(w, x, y, z)] = value; }
    }

    // ... implement ICollection
}

var scope = new MyMultiKeyDictionary 
{
    {
        Tuple.Create(1, 1, 1), "test"
    }
};

textBox1.Text = scope[0, 1, 1, 1];
```

But dictionaries are useful if you have arbitrary keys. If you know your keys are all going to vary from 0 to N, a simple `string[][][]` is the easiest solution.